# Horizontal and Vertical scroll not work for bitmapfield in blackberry application

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, scroll, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, fieldmanager

I have one `BitmapField` that display image into screen. BitmapField is added into `VerticalFieldManager` and finally this manager is added to mainscreen.
porblem is that if my image is larger than screen size than i have not able scroll image horizontally or vertically.
My code is below :-

```
    VerticalFieldManager ver = new   VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|VerticalFieldManager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|VerticalFieldManager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
    Bitmap enc_img = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("4.png");

    btm_fld = new BitmapField(enc_img);

    ver.add(btm_fld); 
    add(ver);
```

What i am doing wrong here.
thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code may help you to get the `VerticalFieldManager` scrollable:

```
long style = VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | 
    HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR;

VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(style);
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();

Bitmap enc_img = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("4.png");
BitmapField btm_fld = new BitmapField(enc_img);

hfm.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));
hfm.add(btm_fld);
hfm.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));

vfm.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));
vfm.add(hfm);
vfm.add(new NullField(NullField.FOCUSABLE));

add(vfm);
```

But the `BitmapField` itself will not be scrollable.

Link to an article in Blackberry Development Knowledge Base, [Create a scrollable image field.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-scrollable-image-field/ta-p/444955)

Comment: @MrVincenzo some time if there is no other focusable field the focus always remain on the field which have focus. so if you click outside the field or any where at the screen  it will assume that you have clicked the field. I think thats why added `NullField`.

Comment: @Rupak Thanks.Link you provide is very useful for me.